# Install Python 3.0, now I cannot get my functions to work

Tags: python, function

I installed Python 3.0 and now I can't get my code to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
def print_multiples(n, high):
    for i in range(1, high+1):
        print(n * i, end='   ')
    print()

def print_mult_table(high):
    for i in range(1, high+1):
        print_multiples(i, high)

print print_mult_table(7)
```

My output looks like this:

```
File "chp7.py", line 82
print print_mult_table(7)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: doesn't `print print_mult_table(7)` need paranthesis also like `print(print_mult_table(7))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3 print() is a function not a statement so you should use:

```
 print(print_mult_table(7))
```

Comment: (*facepalm) Thank you for your enlightenment.

Comment: @user1091975 hehe, it's a double whammy since you have the correct syntax 7 lines above ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is a syntax error because `print` is no longer a *statement* in Python3

Probably

```
print_mult_table(7)
```

without the `print` in front will do what you want. Since the function does some printing itself, unless you also wish to print the return value, which is None in this case